# How to add additional field in joomla 3 and 2.5?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, article-manager, form-fields-types

I'm trying to add additional fields in the Joomla 3.x and 2.5 article manager as explained here

http://www.kavdesign.net/blog/coding/how-to-add-additional-field-in-the-joomla-article-administrator-page/

Where is the location of the following items in Joomla 2.5 and 3.x files needed to edit:

```
jos_content table in joomla database
root/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php
root/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/form.php
root/administrator/components/com_content/models/article.xml
root/administrator/components/admin.content.html.php
root/administrator/components/config.xml
root/libraries/joomla/database/table/content.php
```

Comment: You have written the location of these items. What different answer would you expect?

Comment: this location is in joomla 1.5 but i want the location in joomla 3.x and joomla 2.5

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/how-to-save-custom-fields-in-core-components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any point to follow a tutorial for Joomla 1.5, when you try to work on J3.

There are so many differences between the 2 versions.

For what you want to do, a simple google search would give you plenty of resources.

Here there are some:

[How to save Custom Fields in Core components](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/how-to-save-custom-fields-in-core-components)

[Add custom / extra field to a category](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/add-custom-extra-field-to-a-category)

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin

http://www.joomlart.com/tutorials/joomla-tutorials/adding-joomla-custom-fields-in-article-with-t3-framework

https://zunostudios.com/blog/development/203-how-to-add-custom-fields-to-articles-in-joomla

http://www.aixeena.org/aixeena-lab/aixeena-easy-cck

Comment: tanks this link is very useful https://zunostudios.com/blog/development/203-how-to-add-custom-fields-to-articles-in-joomla